# Where I can find my WADL? (CXF)

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf

I have developed a simple `RESTful` service using `Apache CXF` coupled in a web application and is working fine.

I Can access it on "`http://localhost:8080/SpringRestProjectJava/api/books/1234`" and I am also getting the proper `JSON` response.

My understanding is that [from this link](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html#JAXRSServicesDescription-WADLAutoGenerationatRuntime) that `WADL` will be autogenerated.

Is it correct? If yes, how can I see `WADL` for this service.

This is my `web.xml`

```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/CustomSpringConfig.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>      
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>simplerest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jaxrs.serviceClasses</param-name>
        <param-value>org.gsdev.ws.bookservice.BookResource</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jaxrs.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>org.gsdev.ws.bookservice.provider.XstreamJsonProvider</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>simplerest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

This is my `BookResource.java`

```
@Path( "books/{isbn}" )
public class BookResource {

    @GET
    @Produces ( "application/json" )
    public Book getDetails( @PathParam("isbn") String isbn){

        if( isbn.equals( "1234" )){
            Book book = new Book();
            book.setIsbn(isbn);
            book.setTitle("Learning web services by Garry");
            return book;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after keep on trying I am able to make it work. I think its due to the `CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet`. I made below changes and I was able to access the autogenerated `WADL`.

Changes to `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>simplerest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>simplerest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Added `cxf-servlet.xml` in `WEB-INF`

```
<jaxrs:server id="bookService" address="/bookservice">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
           <ref bean="bs"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean='jsonProvider' />
        </jaxrs:providers>
     </jaxrs:server>

     <bean id="bs" class="org.gsdev.ws.bookservice.BookResource"/> 
     <bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.gsdev.ws.bookservice.provider.XstreamJsonProvider"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

http://localhost:8080/SpringRestProjectJava/api/books?_WADL

By the way lots of goodies here:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html

Comment: I have already tried it and not working getting 404. The link that I provided is part of that documentation only.